# erlang 23 24 version, get_stacktrace problem， All related library need to upgrade?

Tags: erlang

I am trying to use erlang jit and webview function. It only exists in erlang 24.
Because erlang 24's

```
erlang:get_stacktrace
```

not allowed to use, I have changed it in my application.
Like rebar3, add one macro:

```
-ifdef(fun_stacktrace).
-define(WITH_STACKTRACE(T, R, S), T:R -> S = erlang:get_stacktrace(),).
-else.
-define(WITH_STACKTRACE(T, R, S), T:R:S ->).
-endif.
```

But when compiling again, I realized the all related applications of program should be changed, otherwise it's still impossible to use erlang jit and webview.
Like lager application is not compatible with erlang 24.

Is it true? I must change other's application one by one if I want to you erlang 24 or up.

Comment: Looking at the [lager README file](https://github.com/erlang-lager/lager#3x-changelog), it seems like Erlang 24 is supported as of release 3.9.2.

Comment: lager doesn't have use get_stacktrace, I have already searched the code. But it is a problem, all used application have to be checked one by one, even if it's been compiled already.